# How to display images in navigable modal?

Tags: php, html, css

Need help!

I am creating an online portal for which I am displaying images as categories using PHP in grid format. I am displaying images from a folder.

What I am trying to do is create modal for images so that when I click on a particular image, the image Modal opens and displays that particular image in large size with navigation buttons so that I can navigate forward and backward to another image.

Here's what I have till now to just display images using php:

```
<?php

$cols   = 4;
$colCtr = 0;
if($colCtr %$cols == 0)
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr><tr>";
$folder = "./upload";
    $results = scandir('./upload/');
    foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
  echo '<td>
        <a href="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" target="_blank""/><img src="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" target="_blank" alt="..." style="margin-left:50px;margin-bottom:27px;width:289px;height:190px;border: 2px solid black;" class="w3-hover-opacity hover-shadow cursor">
        </td></tr>';

            }
           }     
$colCtr++;
echo "\r\n";
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use a lightbox javascript plugin to do that. why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: But will it be enough to create modal and navigation for every image it fetches?

Comment: You need to search for the one that does it. for example this might do that: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Ok, I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lightbox javascript plugin to do that. Like: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 0):

Try this js plugin. It is easy to use is simple. http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, yeah! This applies to both the links provided as answers because after some time, the links may not work as what usually happens. This is suitable for short period. It surely helped me but may not work for someone later.